# sql NOT LIKE syntax

Tags: sql, teradata

I need to filter based on a timestamp and would like to get everything within a certain day. The timestamps are like this: `02/06/2014 7:45:59 AM` or translated `2014-02-06 07:45:59`

```
select * 
from P_FAR_SBXD.T_CLAIM_SERVICE_TYP_DIM 
where service_type_id = 134469888 and valid_from_tsp not like '2014-02-06 %'
```

When I run this query, I am returned the error: `Partial String matching requires character operands`

Upon searching this error, I was given `The user used the partial string matching operator (LIKE) with an argument that was not a character string.`

So what can I use to match a date? **edit:** or in this case, not a date?

Comment: Are valid_from_tsp a timestamp or a string? If it's a timestamp you should use a date function. I don't know teradata, but something like: `cast(valid_from_tsp as date) = '2014-02-06'`

Comment: What is the datatype of `valid_from_tsp`?

Comment: timestamp `02/19/2014 7:45:59 AM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just cast to a date and compare to your desired date, something like;

```
SELECT * 
FROM P_FAR_SBXD.T_CLAIM_SERVICE_TYP_DIM 
WHERE service_type_id = 134469888 
 AND CAST(valid_from_tsp AS DATE) = '2014-02-06'
```

EDIT: If you have a large table, this query will not use indexes well. If that is important, just do a range check between midnight and next midnight instead;

```
SELECT * 
FROM P_FAR_SBXD.T_CLAIM_SERVICE_TYP_DIM 
WHERE service_type_id = 134469888 
 AND valid_from_tsp >= '2014-02-06' AND valid_from_tsp < '2014-02-07'
```

Comment: @staples Hm, that should work, hard to tell what goes wrong. The rows have id 134469888 and another date?

Comment: I checked my data again, I was wrong, and it does work

Comment: This would be inefficient in long lists, as the CAST will be applied to all values of valid_from_tsp before processing the logic, negating any indexing.

Comment: @Matt True, added a version that does a range check that can be pre-calculated instead.

Answer (score 3):

The following is a better way to express the date condition:

```
select * 
from P_FAR_SBXD.T_CLAIM_SERVICE_TYP_DIM 
where service_type_id = 134469888 and
      valid_from_tsp >= DATE '2014-02-06' and
      valid_from_tsp < DATE '2014-02-07';
```

or:

```
select * 
from P_FAR_SBXD.T_CLAIM_SERVICE_TYP_DIM 
where service_type_id = 134469888 and
      valid_from_tsp >= DATE '2014-02-06' and
      valid_from_tsp < DATE '2014-02-06' + interval '1' day;
```

The difference is important.  In general, when you have a function on a column, the database does not use indexes.  So these forms will use an index on the column.  The best index for this query is `T_CLAIM_SERVICE_TYP_DIM(service_type_id, valid_from_tsp)`.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
select * from P_FAR_SBXD.T_CLAIM_SERVICE_TYP_DIM 
where service_type_id = 134469888 and 
not DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, valid_from_tsp)) = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @your_date))
```

Answer (score 0):

LIKE operator is for text.

Just a guess (you did not provide table structure), but probably `valid_from_tsp` is not a varchar column, but a timestamp or date column.

So , instead of

```
valid_from_tsp not like '2014-02-06 %'
```

you should use this:

```
cast(valid_from_tsp as varchar(20)) not like '2014-02-06 %'`
```